# how to implement monorepo with gradle and multiple gradle projects

Tags: gradle, bazel, monorepo

We have a few full gradle projects A, B, C, D.  These are microservices that are going to start sharing the protobuf generated java files.  we are thinking a structure like this

```
A
    build.gradle (this is a full on gradle build)
B
    build.gradle (this is B's full on gradle)
common
    build.gradle (build the protobuf that is used by A and B)
```

Now, the question is how do we make sure that when a developer builds A, it also builds common in case it changed on his git pull.  Same goes for B.  The settings.gradle file didn't seem to hav a ../../:project or something like that.

I do remember gradle came out with a way to build multiple gradle projects though as well.

Ideally, when someone changes common, multiple jenkins builds would be kicked off as well verifying that changing core code didn't break any of the services that use it.  I am not quite sure how to

```
1. document the things that depend on common
2. use the document to kick off builds of all things depending on common
```

Then if this were to grow, and you have D depends on C depends on common, each build needs to be kicked off feeding the binary upstream from common to C and then C's jar and common's jar to D.  I know 'pants' is used at twitter to do this.  Google is using bazel.  Perhaps I look into that instead of gradle? or can we intermingle them?

Answer (score 2):

Simply declaring a dependency on `common` should be sufficient enough:

```
// Project A's build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":common"))
}
```

In order to build `a`, the build of `common` would need to succeed. If the build of `common` failed for whatever reason, then then build of `a` will also fail. Example:

```
$ ./gradlew project-a:build
> Task :common:compileJava FAILED
/Users/cisco/code/example-multi-project/common/src/main/java/common/ExampleCommon.java:6: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
        return 1;
               ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':common:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

You can see in the above that when I tried to build project a (`project-a:build`), the common's build task was invoked (`:common:compileJava`).

Both projects a/b/etc should have thorough tests (unit, integration, smoke, etc) to make sure that any incompatible changes are detected early/often.

You can read more about multi-project builds in the official guide: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html